# Convert FormFile to Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-blob-storage

I am doing an ASP .NET Core MVC web application. There is a module in the web application to upload a file to blob storage.

Following is the function I employ to upload a file to the blob storage:

```
public CloudBlockBlob UploadBlob(string BlobName, string ContainerName, IFormFile file)
{
    CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerName.ToLower());
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(BlobName);

    try
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync((Stream) file); //trying to convert FormFile to Stream type object and upload to blob storage
        return blockBlob;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var r = e.Message;
        return null; 
    }
}
```

There, I have already cast the **FormFile** object `'file'` to **Stream** object as given in the `try` block.
But instead of uploading the file to the blob storage, gives the **Exception:**

> `Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile' to type 'System.io.stream'`

***Question:***
Is it possible to cast an IFormFile object to Stream or Is there any other proper way to do it?

Thank you.

**PS:** To get an input file I have to use FormFile type object, but to upload file to the blob storage I have to use Stream type object. So, to solve the issue anyhow I have to convert the input FormFile to an Stream type object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a MemoryStream and copy the content of the form file to it then upload the content of the memory stream.

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    await file.CopyToAsync(ms);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
}
```

Comment: Mr. Karl, thank you for your answer. Could you please explain what this cancellationToken is? I did not get it.

Comment: Oh sorry, copied this from some of my current code. CancellationTokens are used to cancel async call chains. You can just remove it if you don't use them in your project.

Comment: Yes, your code is working very well. I highly appreciate your clear answer.

Comment: This reads the entire file into memory which will be problematic for large files. Use the solutions below that recommend using `file.OpenReadStream()` instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
    blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.Openreadstream());
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 5):

To convert FormFile to stream :

```
var stream = [YourFormFile].OpenReadStream();
```